# Refactoring ActiveRecord query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord query that pulls a randomly selected Matchup object where neither player in the matchup is on a team whose current opponent's name is "Bye Week".

**Model Definition:**

Matchup has two fields, player_1 and player_2, which are the ID of a Player object.

Each player belongs_to Team, which has several fields, e.g. opponent_week_1, opponent_week_2 ... opponent_week_17.

current_week returns an integer between 1 and 17 based on today's date (it determines what week of the NFL season we are currently in).

Right now I am doing it like this, but I would like to remove the loop, and use just a query to select an object, at random, that meets the condition:

```
def getRandomMatchup
  current_week = view_context.current_week

  matchup = Matchup.order("RANDOM()").first

  opponent1 = Team.find(Player.find(m.player_1).team.send("opp_week_#{current_week}")).name    
  opponent2 = Team.find(Player.find(m.player_2).team.send("opp_week_#{current_week}")).name

  while opponent1 == "Bye Week" || opponent2 == "Bye Week"
    matchup = Matchup.order("RANDOM()").first

    opponent1 = Team.find(Player.find(matchup.player_1).team.send("opp_week_#{current_week}")).name
    opponent2 = Team.find(Player.find(matchup.player_2).team.send("opp_week_#{current_week}")).name
  end 

  return matchup
end
```

My thought was to do something like this, but I'm not sure how to execute it correctly:

```
m = Matchup.where.not(Team.find(Player.find(m.player_1).team.send("opp_week_#{current_week}")).name: "Bye Week",
    Team.find(Player.find(m.player_2).team.send("opp_week_#{current_week}")).name: "Bye Week").order("RANDOM()").first
```

I am using Ruby 2 and Rails 4.

Comment: Well, that's a bit confusing. So are `player_1` and `player_2` foreign keys or do those methods return the actual player objects? Also, can you post the definition of that method being called via `send`?

Comment: I second to depa. Paste please Your table structure. And provide some examples in fashion:
These are the records I have: .....
These I want to be fetched: ......

Comment: Yup, at least post how Team, Player, and Matchup are associated.  And please use descriptive variable names!  ```o1```, ```o2```, and ```m``` don't tell the reader anything.

Comment: @depa, I've added descriptions and updated the variable names, any suggestions?

Comment: @EdgarsJekabsons, I've added descriptions and updated the variable names, any suggestions?

Comment: @jcm, I've added descriptions and updated the variable names, any suggestions?

Comment: Hmm, so I take it opponent_week_n attributes aren't backed up by database columns?  That's why you need to use send?  And opponent1 and opponent2 are Strings?

Comment: Have You any associations defined on Your models ?

Comment: @jcm, opponent_week_n are database columns on Team, and each player belongs_to a Team (player.team.opp_week_n gives the ID of the opponent team).

Comment: @EdgarsJekabsons, yes, but probably not enough. The only one I'm currently using is Player belongs_to Team (e.g. player.team.name = "Jets")

Comment: Please post all your model associations. I still don't get your data model.

Comment: @depa, the only model association is Player belongs_to Team. I realize it's probably not enough, but it is working for now and I am trying to roll this out quickly, with plans to refactor afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to generate Matchups between two random players whose opposing teams for the current week aren't 'Bye Week'?

How about

```
Player.joins(:teams).where.not('team.opponent_week_#{current_week}' => 'Bye Week').limit(2)
```

Now, that doesn't take care of randomness and leaves open the possibility that both players belong to the same team.

Edit:

```
Matchup.joins(:players).where('players.id = ? OR players.id = ?', player_1, player_2).joins(:teams).where.not('team.opponent_week_#{current_week}' => 'Bye Week')
```

Comment: Sort of. I'm not generating a Matchup, they are all generated and stored on the Matchup model. I am selecting a Matchup at random where neither player in the Matchup are on a team who's current opponent is "Bye Week". Does that make sense?

Comment: @jackerman09 So all possible Matchups already exist?  Instead of picking a Matchup at random and see if it satisfies conditions, why not enforce the conditions at Matchup generation?  Nevermind, I know why: because the conditions (bye or not) change week to week.

Comment: correct all Matchups already exist, and you're exactly right about them changing week to week. Any thoughts on how to do this? My thought was to query records that meet the condition of non-bye-week and then order them randomly and take the first record, but I'm not sure how to get the initial query.

Comment: See the edit.  That should return an array of Matchups, if so just pick a random one.